# Load embed youtube video in fullscreen mode by button click - iOS

Tags: ios, video, youtube

So the question is:

Can i load load embed youtube video in fullscreen mode, by button click, skip intermediate UIWebView?

Googling gave me only one answer - probably NO, but hope still alive.

Comment: can't you simply open a fullscreen uiwebview with an embed youtube video on button click?

Comment: I can. And if im not figure out how do it in the way i want, i have to do the way you suggest. But fullscreen in UIWebView != Fullscreen YouTube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried embedding the video as a fullscreen page?
Something like:

```
<object style="height: 768px; width: 1024px">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/gPLb9FVKoqI?version=3&feature=player_detailpage">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/gPLb9FVKoqI?version=3&feature=player_detailpage" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="1024" height="768">
```

...and then present it in a fullscreen UIWebView?

This is assuming you somehow generate yourself the embedded pages (which shouldn't be difficult if you know the video id)

Other than that, I don't see what other options you might have.