# How to play a youtube video list in ios natively

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

I need to play youtube video lists in an iphone app. I did a quick research but still could not find the answer. Most of the answers out there are about playing a single youtube video in iOS by embedding a youtube url in a HTML page and load it in a UIWebview. But it doesn't seem to be the way for playing a list. But I guess it's possible because there are apps that can do that.

Update: I managed to play a list in a UIWebView with iframe method, but it not what i set out to do. I need to play the video not in a full screen mode. Is there anyway to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using UIWebView's internal [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953), it may be possible to load the videos one by one by storing their URLs in an array and incrementing the array's object position when the finish event is sent internally by the iFrame's javascript.  iFrame methods are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), and a way to inject a webview with javascript is shown [here](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview).

As for non-inline video playing (only fullscreen), set `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to NO on the UIWebView.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Do you mean the direct Youtube video URLs? AFAIK, MPMoviePlayerController can not play a youtube video given a URL like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<id of the video>.

Comment: Oh... I assumed you had these things local... Well, the approach is nearly the same, except you'd have to use a UIWebView, and they are known to be finicky.

Comment: Thanks, iframe in a UIwebview works, I updated my question. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It doesnt work, i found this in UIWebView's doc: "In order for video to play inline, not only does this property need to be set on the view, but the video element in the HTML document must also include the webkit-playsinline attribute.". Youtube doesn't allow to set this properties for <video> tag created by iframe methods.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205122/load-embed-youtube-video-in-fullscreen-mode-by-button-click-ios) will help.